# Distance between left edge of control and right edge of its container client area

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, distance

I have a control of which I have to find the distance between the left of the control and the right of the client area.

The Control.Right property

> Gets the distance, in pixels, between the **right** edge of the control and the **left** edge of its container's client area.

The Control.Left property does the same but with the **left** edge of the control and the **left** edge of its container's client area.

However, I want to know if there is an inbuilt method that

> Gets the distance, in pixels, between the **left** edge of the control and the **right** edge of its container's client area.

My current working code.

```
int distance = container.Width - control.Location.X
```

Comment: that code looks good, what's the problem?

Comment: Everything is OK, I just wanted to know if there was an already existing way of measuring it. I guess that if Control.Right and Control.Left existed, there probably is.

Comment: You guess wrong.  What you are doing is what you must do.